# Register javascript array from code behind in facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, facebook

I need to set a javascript array from code behind using C# in Asp.Net2008 the problem now is that when i register the array using the following C# code:

```
string ArrVal = "";
        string Sep = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
        {   
            ArrVal += Sep + FilesCount[i].ToString();
            Sep = ",";
        }         
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("FilesArr", ArrVal);
```

And the Client code is :

```
var FileName = FilesArr[0];
```

in any web application it is working well but at my application that is released in the facebook platform the javascript code doesn't see the array but in ordinary web application the javscript code see the registered array

can any one tell me why this problem occurrs ?

Thanks in advance for any reply and trial.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you developing an IFrame application? If so, you may have run into the P3P issue, where the ASP.Net session doesn't get passed from the main frame to the IFrame.
   Take a look at [this link](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/ASP.NET#Solution_to_an_IE_gotcha_when_developing_Facebook_App_in_an_IFRAME) for a possible solution.
2. Another thing to figure out is what is the nature of the problem: is it that the array does not get passed from the code-behind to JavaScript, or that it gets passed, but without values? Try adding an `alert(FilesArr);` at the very top of your script, and see if it prints `object` or a JavaScript error.
3. Finally, just to qualify the issue, test it in another browser. Is this just an IE problem, or does it occur in Firefox as well? If it's consistent across browsers, you knowyou need to focus on the ASP.Net side of things :)

Hope any of these helped.

Comment: I am already using this code of overriding the method onOprerender()
and the problem existed and i have tried it in IE not firefox i didn't know what is the result in the firefox or other browsers and the array is not declared at all and javascript error reported not an empty array

Comment: Try forcing the issue. 
1. Add a string variable to the page class:
    protected string FilesArr; 
2. In the Page_Load add something like:
    FilesArr= "var FilesArr = {1,2,3,4};";
3. In your HTML page, at the top of the script add the following:
<% Response.Write(FilesArr); %>

Run the page now and see if the array is available.
Good luck.